# Does iplot work with python version >2.7 with cufflinks package?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have this code in jupyter notebook `

```
   df = cars[['cyl', 'wt', 'mpg']]

   layout = dict(
               title = 'Chart from Pandas DataFrame',
               xaxis = dict(title = 'x-axis'),
               yaxis = dict(title = 'y-axis')
   )

   df.iplot(filename = 'cf-simple-line-chart', layout = layout)`
```

the cars dataset can be found at https://github.com/syedRumman/Python-and-Data-Science.git

I am using python 3.7 version. When I try to use the df.iplot(), I get this error

```
#The data property of a figure may only be assigned a list or tuple that contains a permutation of a subset of itself
Invalid trace(s) with uid(s): {None}
```

When I call

```
df.iplot(filename = 'cf-simple-line-chart', layout = layout)
```

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNekY.png)

Is iplot() incompatible with pandas dataframe library in version >2.7?